# Calendar - time interval

Tags: java

I have following Java method and it returns String depending on time interval. It works fine when the intervals are like 6-14h.

```
private String shiftCount()
{
  Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
  if ((time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >=  0) && (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <  6)) return "-S1";
  if ((time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >=  6) && (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 14)) return "-S2";
  if ((time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 14) && (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 22)) return "-S3";
  if ((time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 22) && (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 24)) return "-S1";   
  return null;
}
```

But what if i need e.g. 6:10-14:10 interval?

Comment: You have to check the hours and the minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to write "using some integrated function" or "simple solution"; I was looking for something like isInInterval(start, end) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need intervals as each region touches the other.

```
private String shiftCount() {
  Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
  // the hours is always >= 0
  if (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <  6) return "-S1";
  if (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 14) return "-S2";
  if (time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 22) return "-S3";
  // the hour is always < 24.
  return "-S1";   
}
```

or you could use a long for the time of day which allows you to use any combination of hours/minutes etc.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
// time of the day in minutes.
long time = ((now + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(now)) % 86400000) / 60000;
if (time <  6*60 + 10) return "-S1";
if (time < 14*60 + 10) return "-S2";
if (time < 22*60) return "-S3";
return "-S1";
```

Comment: The second option above will fail on DST change days

Comment: @JodaStephen, The second example handles daylight saving changes in much the same way as the first. i.e. it uses the same underlying method.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to also check the `MINUTE` field.

With joda-time this would be less verbose.

Comment: Thanks, it's enough, I only needed to know if exists some function for this kind of problem, something like isInInterval(start, end) :]

Comment: joda-time has `new Interval(start, end)`